# Solution of gases (i. e. carbon dioxide) in water

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, climate-science

This question is related to my former question "Dissolution of Carbon Dioxide in water" and thanks for previous replies. It looks not so easy, so allow me to restate it (*)

Is there a textbook chapter or even an article that describes in general how the solubility of a gas in water depends on the water depth?
From my point of view, it can be a purely theoretical consideration, which alone considers an ideal gas in pure water.

(*) I dont't know how it is possible to ask an older but modified question again, so this post is new.

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Re, "depends on water depth." If it depends on depth, then the most likely explanation is that it depends on _pressure,_ which, in its turn, depends on depth. You might have better luck searching for "solubility vs. pressure" instead of "solubility vs. depth."

Comment: I have to add: suppose the system is in diffusive equilibrium. Because of the gravitational gradient, a particle is more likely to diffuse from top to bottom than from bottom to top. A concentration gradient would have to counteract this.
It has already been pointed out to me that this gradient must be very small. That may be the case, I haven't been able to calculate it correctly yet.
I would be very grateful for a reference, be it on theory or a measurement.